# From a virtual machine, how can't I access the host by name?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM/QEMU virtual machine created in Virtual Machine Manager.

From this machine I can ping the host by IP, but I can't ping it by hostname:

```
elopio@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ping 192.168.2.207
PING 192.168.2.207 (192.168.2.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms

elopio@ubuntu-xenial:~$ host calchas
calchas has address 127.0.1.1
```

So, if I try to access calchas (the host, ip=192.168.2.207) by name from ubuntu-xenial (the guest), I will be accessing the guest instead.

How can I ping the host by name?

Comment: Examine `/etc/resolv.conf`, `man resolvconf`, `man nsswitch`, `/etc/hosts`, `dig -x 192.168.2.207` on `elopio`, to start.

Comment: Thanks. With dig I found that I could ping with calchas.lan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to append .lan to the hostname:

```
$ ping calchas.lan
PING calchas.lan (192.168.2.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from calchas.lan (192.168.2.207): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.151 ms
```